# NodeJs is returning first document only

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJs and MongoDb as a back-end service.In my collection i have several documents having fields named _id and Name but Node is returning only first document and showing error in console.I want to fetch only Name field of a document.

Error:

[image: Error]

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');    
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 

app.post('/offers',(req, res) => {

 MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {           
    if(err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db('Tiffino_db');

    dbo.collection("Offers")
        .find({},{ projection: { _id: 0 } })
        .toArray((err, result) => {
             if (err) {
                     console.log("Error:", +err);
                 }
                 else { 
                    for(var i = 0;i<result.length;i++){
                      res.send(result[i].Name);
                    }
                   db.close();
                }
           });
     });
});
```

Please let me know what I did wrong in above code.

**THANKS**

Comment: Use Mongoose npm

Comment: But how can I implement using mongodb driver.

Comment: mongoose provide callback , so you will send data once all data has been retrived

Comment: @SaurabhMistry mongodb package also provides all data once and its faster than mongoose as it uses raw drivers directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to send multiple responses in a loop using Response.Send() as a response is only sent once.
This won't work, you'll need to create an array of names, and then use Response.Send() to do this once.

Using `res.send(result.map(r => r.name))` would probably work

Comment: Yeah, it fetches all the results but error is still there.

Comment: Did you remove the loop? If not I'm guessing you are attempting to change the Response headers after using Response.send()
You can only edit the headers before doing this.
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Answer (score 1):

You should aggregate the results into a variable and then call res.send() only once:

```
let resultString;
for(var i = 0;i<result.length;i++){
   resultString += result[i].Name + '\n';
}
res.send(resultString);
```

If you want to stream the results, you can use res.write() and when done call res.end()

Comment: how can I aggregate the result could you please provide the code.

Comment: @Digvijay can you approve the solution you chose?

Answer (score 1):

```
...
...
else { 
    output = result.map(offer => offer.name);
    res.send({output});
    db.close();
}
```

This should work as you can only send response once on a single `response` object and you are calling that for `results.length` times.

Comment: Thanks Ridham, that worked it is sending data in the form of array how can i get it in the form of json object.

Comment: @Digvijay , use `res.json(result)`

Comment: Updated the code, If you want to have specific format please edit the question and post the format

Comment: ["a", "b", "c"] is itself a valid json

Answer (score 1):

You can not use res.send() multiple time in a for loop, try somthing like this

```
var data=[];
for(var i = 0;i<result.length;i++){
                  data.push(result[i].Name);
                }
res.send(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/offers',(req, res) => {

 MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {           
    if(err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db('Tiffino_db');

    dbo.collection("Offers")
        .find({},{ projection: { _id: 0 } })
        .toArray((err, results) => {
             if (err) {
                     console.log("Error:", +err);
                 }
                 else { 

                   response = results.map(result => result.Name);
                   //res.send(response);
                   // in json format
                   res.json(response);
                   db.close();
                }
           });
     });
});
```

Comment: @Digvijay , use `res.json(response)` to give output in json format

Comment: When i use res.json({"Name":response}); i get data in json array like this {"Name" : ["India","UK",....] },how can i get this in json objects something like this [ {"Name":India},{"Name":UK}....]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to be calling `res.send(...)` multiple times. Since you're calling it inside a loop, it will send the first document and fail in the next as expected.